# I am developing a website I know bootstrap and learned spring I want to know what else can be done to make it better?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-applications, backend, web-frontend

I want to know what spring dependencies should I use on my website to make the work easy and spring or spring boot which one is better. also, suggest some frontend technologies that I can use to make the website smart.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very broad question. And it all depends on what features you want in your web site. Just listing few basic module to give you some hints.

- **Spring MVC** - For web application with MVC Pattern
- **Spring Security** - To secure your app
- **Spring ORM** - If using any ORM tool like hibernate

You need to explore more on the basis of your need.

**Spring Boot vs Spring:**

You should use Spring Boot if you are starting new project. Spring Boot came to make development process easier when using Spring Framework. In Spring, developer had to write lots of code to configure beans and dependencies. Spring Boot automated this process so that you no longer do it by yourself but Spring Boot will take care of it. Plus it provides some extra tools (In built Web Server, in Memory DB, tool to  monitor and manage Spring Boot App )

Try to create a simple web app in Spring and Spring Boot to understand the difference.

**Front-end Technologies:**

JavaScript based framework/lib like Angular,React,Vue etc. are the trend for front-end now a days. Again there are pros and cons of each of them. Hence you need to evaluate, what suits you better as per your requirement.